# sitecore: unable to access analytic (Login fail)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

All the databases are stored in a remote server where I need to access remotely.
I need to access to Analytic db from my code behind file to get most viewed page.
So, I tried with something like this:

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=xxxx ;User id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;");
```

But an exception was thrown (Login in failed ... )
And I have found few guides, but not really understand how it is used.

Guide 1: using Creating LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer) as mentioned in http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/09/mostviewedList.aspx
can anyone tell me or guide me what should I do? I have totally 0 idea on doing this.

Guide 2: using configuration manager (I haven't tried this yet)

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

Comment: Please share the exception message, because the info you provided is not clear at all. It's also questionable that you need to access the Analytics database directly instead of using the Sitecore API... what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Sitecore are you using? Are you using OMS or DMS? The article you linked to is for querying OMS, in Sitecore 6.5/DMS you should just be querying via the Sitecore.Analytics API and therefore should need a sql connection reference.

[How to get item page views using sitecore 6.5 Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733321/how-to-get-item-page-views-using-sitecore-6-5-analytics-api)

Comment: Jammykam : currently using sitecore6.6, I'm not really sure I'm using OMS or DMS as the project was setup by others. I tried to search in my project bin file, and didn't find any Sitecore.Analytics.dll file.
Is there any difference between OMS and DMS? When I have a peek in the sql management studio, I noticed one of the database name Sitecore.Analytic, does it imply that I'm using DMS?

Comment: If you're using 6.6 then it will be DMS. Versions prior to 6.4 used OMS. There should definitely be a `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` in your `bin` directory, I just checked mine and it was there (6.5 and 6.6)

Comment: Yupe, I had my project to reference it. But when i tried to use this code itecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable pagesDataTable = new VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable();
my visual studio intellisense can't detect it. 
but anyway, I access to the db using ConfigurationManager. I wonder is it a best way of doing it?

Comment: I had a look at the DLL in [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and that class is there... I didn't look into the implementation details though. I presume it is a project set up issue. Make sure you have added it to your using statements too. I don't think accessing the DB is the correct way of doing it, you should use the API provided. It will also make any future upgrades easier in case of any breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

[Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897938/jim) mentions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008249/sitecore-6-5-accessing-analytics-database) that he ended up writing his own calls. May be he might be a source of more information.

Moreover I am not aware that what exactly is your requirement but have a quick look at [this page](https://github.com/Velir/Sitecore-Analytics) and see if this code offers what your are after.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Btw, I managed to solve using ConfigurationManager to access to the analytic db and retrieve using query provided by http://jo-zhou.blogspot.com/2012/07/get-most-popular-pages-in-sitecore.html

Comment: Good. Thanks for sharing the blog post. Did any of the above helped in the research?